# Aggregate time series from list of dictionaries (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, aggregate

I have a list of dictionaries generated as such:

```
all_series = []
    # loop
    ...
    all_series.append({"name": a.name, "sector": a.sector, "ts":a.ts})
    ...
```

name and sector are strings, ts is a pandas time series indexed by date.

Summing all time series together irrespective of name/sector is easy:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x.add(y, fill_value=0), [a["ts"] for a in all_series])
```

Now I want to do this summing, but grouped by sector - i.e. I'd like to get one summed time series by sector and stored in some sensible way. I'm able to easily do this for one hard-coded sector of choice, but can you think of a good way of doing this in a more flexible way?

I guess ideally I get one data frame back, with one column per summed sector?

Comment: The time frame is the same for all of them?

Comment: Nope, not quiet - it's okay to assume 0 for the gaps/mismatches when summing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested answer didn't work after all, because it didn't account for different lengths and start/end dates of the individual time series.

This is how I solved it in the end:

```
pd.concat({(a.sector, a.name): a.ts for i, a in all_series.iterrows()}, axis=1).groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum()
```

Thanks for the inspiration!

Answer (score 1):

You can use default `pd.DataFrame` constructor, `agg` these series after `groupby` and then `sum`

```
pd.DataFrame(all_series).groupby('sector').ts.agg(tuple).transform(lambda k: sum(k)).T

sector                      sector1 sector2
2018-07-27 10:30:34.057044  102     40
2018-07-28 10:30:34.057044  91      36
2018-07-29 10:30:34.057044  153     163
2018-07-30 10:30:34.057044  119     114
```

---

*Using sample data (if others want try other solutions):*

```
all_series = []
now = datetime.datetime.now()
all_series.append({"name": 'name1',
                   "sector": 'sector1', 
                   "ts": pd.Series(np.random.randint(100, size=4), 
                                   index=pd.date_range(start=now, freq='D',periods=4))})
all_series.append({"name": 'name1',
                   "sector": 'sector1', 
                   "ts": pd.Series(np.random.randint(100, size=4), 
                                   index=pd.date_range(start=now, freq='D',periods=4))})
all_series.append({"name": 'name2',
                   "sector": 'sector2', 
                   "ts": pd.Series(np.random.randint(100, size=4), 
                                   index=pd.date_range(start=now, freq='D',periods=4))})
all_series.append({"name": 'name2',
                   "sector": 'sector2', 
                   "ts": pd.Series(np.random.randint(100, size=4), 
                                   index=pd.date_range(start=now, freq='D',periods=4))})
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much - pretty much all of "ts.agg(tuple).transform(lambda k: sum(k)).T" was new to me, still have a lot to learn!

Comment: Actually, I have just noticed this doesn't work as expected. The date indices don't seem to kept across operations, and given every single series has different start and end dates the data gets mixed up...